# Sensitivity analysis for specific sets of constraints on DoCplex

Tags: optimization, python, docplex, cplex-python-api, sensitivity-analysis

I am working on DoCplex to run a large model with several variables and constraints. I used the following link from [sensitivity analysis in python + Docplex](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7546/sensitivity-analysis-in-python-docplex) to run the sensitivity analysis. In that example, there was a limited number of constraints and variables, which made it easy to interpret, but with a very large instance, the task becomes more tedious.

Therefore, I have a question if I name the set of constraints as `mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40==nbbus30, 'samenumberofbuses')`, will it be possible to run sensitivity analysis on the values on the right-hand side of a specific set of constraints? Instead of having the values for `print(cpx.solution.sensitivity.rhs())` which will give me the values on all constraints, I would only have it for what I am focusing on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the results you get from sensitivity.rhs :

See small example out of the [zoo example](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/) again:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
from docplex.mp.relax_linear import LinearRelaxer

mdl = Model(name='buses')  
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')  
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')  
ctKids=mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
ctKids2=mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 290, 'kids2') 
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)   
mdl.solve() 

lp = LinearRelaxer.make_relaxed_model(mdl)
m2 = lp.solve()

cpx = lp.get_engine().get_cplex()



print(cpx.solution.sensitivity.rhs())

rhs=cpx.solution.sensitivity.rhs()

names = cpx.linear_constraints.get_names()
print(names)

#Now we want the result only for constraint "kids"

indexConstraint=names.index("kids")

print("right info for the constraint ",rhs[indexConstraint])
```

which gives

```
[(290.0, 1e+20), (-1e+20, 300.0)]
['kids', 'kids2']
right info for the constraint  (290.0, 1e+20)
```